# Merging overlapping polygons with Dissolve?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, dissolve

I created a service area of multiple facilities and as a result I got a feature class with multiple overlapping polygons of the same value.

[image: Service Area polygons]

To merge all these polygons I tried to use Dissolve tool using "Travel Time" as a dissolve field, however the output of the Dissolve tool is represented in ArcMap as just a single polygon, even though attribute table looks like this ("ToBreak" is in minutes and correspond to "TravelTime"):

[image]

I tried to check/uncheck "Create multipart features" option, but result was always the same. Also when I switch the Dissolve output to hollow symbol, I can see boundaries of merged polygons. Am I missing something? How to merge overlapping polygons?

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the datatype of the dissolve field and provide a partial list of the representative values in the "Travel Time" field.

Comment: @Vince I'm not sure what do you mean by the datatype of the dissolve field, attribute table of the output of dissolve is represented on the second picture. Values in "Travel Time" are from 1 to 5 minutes (correspond to "ToBreak" field).

Comment: You did not state anywhere that ToBreak was "Travel Time".  Please edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently I could have all my polygons with same values merged when doing Service Area by checking "Merge by break value" in Polygon Generation tab. This completely solves my issue.[image]